# Login to a website through html post form and navigate to another page and click an element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page with the following code which logs me in a website:

```
<form id="user-login" action="http://thewebsite.com/user/login/" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="acc123"/>
<input type="hidden" name="pass" value="password"/>
<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="formid"/>
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="user_login"/>
<input type="submit" name="op" value="Log in"/>
</form>
```

The post works and I'm logged in .
Next , while I'm logged in I want to execute another script on the same website but in a different page for executing a button click:

Here's how the website button is defined :

```
<a style="cursor: pointer; " class="vote-this" onclick="doVote(1234)">Click</a>
```

How I'm supposed to do this while logged in? ( to call the onclick event )

Answer (score 1):

Like this? On the page you get redirected to, when you log in.

```
<body onload="doVote(1234)">...</body>
```

Comment: I'm not redirected to the other page when logged in.

Comment: @Jack: Then you should perform the equivalent operation inside the server script. HTML cannot magically trigger scripts in other pages.

Comment: I think you've missunderstood my question : The website on which I'm trying to do these operations is not mine . I'm just trying to log in using those methods.

Comment: You can not use Cross site scripting :-)

Comment: Well , is there any other way I can make a script which opens the page and clicks the button?

Comment: As far as I know, not really. You can not modify the behavior of the existing site. This would be a security risk. You have to do something manually like pasting javascript:doVote(1234); in the javascript console.

Comment: Hmm , actually when clicking the button it makes a POST with the following data ( id=1234 ) so I guess is the same thing like clicking the button . I've tried making a post request but I don't get any results.

Comment: this is the only thing regarding the button on the webpage : <a style="cursor: pointer; " class="vote-this" onclick="doVote(1234)">Click</a> and when I click it it sends a post to another php page with the post data id=1234 . I've tried to do the same with requests but it doesnt work..I guess I need cookies/session..god knows

Comment: Please post the javascript function doVote

Comment: I don't know how the function looks like because the website I'm doing this is not mine . So , when I click the button which executes the doVote it sends a post request to a php file called vote ..that's the only thing I can tell because I don't have other information

Comment: I am not able to help if you can not provide the JavaScript code of the function.